# How to make grunt-contrib-copy not copy LESS files?

Tags: gruntjs

I have the following Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    //Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({      
        copy: {
            main: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: "source/",
                        src: ["!**/*.less", "**"],
                        dest: "compiled/"
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-copy");
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["copy"]);
};
```

My goal is to have it copy everything from the `source` folder to the `compiled` folder. For example, if this was my file structure before running Grunt...

```
[root]
 - Gruntfile.js
 - source
    \- test.txt
    \- sample.html
    \- file.less
 - compiled
```

...I am expecting to get...

```
[root]
 - Gruntfile.js
 - source
    \- test.txt
    \- sample.html
    \- file.less
 - compiled
    \- test.txt
    \- sample.html
```

...but instead I get:

```
[root]
 - Gruntfile.js
 - source
    \- test.txt
    \- sample.html
    \- file.less
 - compiled
    \- test.txt
    \- sample.html
    \- file.less
```

I thought that setting the source to `["!**/*.less", "**"]` would fix this, but that isn't the case. Why doesn't this work (what is it actually targeting) and how can I fix this?

Comment: The `!` negates a previous pattern, so put it after your matching pattern.

Comment: @steveax like this?: `src: ["**/*.less!", "**"]` Or do you mean something like this?: `src: ["**", "!**/*.less"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negating patterns should be placed *after* matching patterns since they negate the previous match:

```
copy: {
  main: {
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        cwd: "source/",
        src: ["**", "!**/*.less"],
        dest: "compiled/"
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

See the [globbing patterns docs](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) for examples, like:

```
// All files in alpha order, but with bar.js at the end.
{src: ['foo/*.js', '!foo/bar.js', 'foo/bar.js'], dest: ...}
```

By placing `"**"` after your negating pattern, you're overriding it.